# Check if Azure Active Directory B2C verification code was sent via email

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using an Azure AD B2C policy where I'm requiring users to verify their email addresses with a verification code.

Is there a way to check the activity on whether or not this verification code email was sent to the user that is signing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are no diagnostics around the verification code email.** The verification code email should be sent every time as per your policy. You can request a feature for diagnostics or something like that in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv)

In some cases, emails will get routed to the user's spam mail or the company might be filtering out the emails completely. If you're seeing users from a given company consistently not receive the email, you should get some confirmation from Microsoft that the email was sent by opening a support ticket.