# Problem with verification code emails not being sent when a user tries to sign up using B2C email form signup process

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

From today 2024-03-01 we have a problem with verification code emails not being sent when a user tries to sign up using B2C email form signup process.

I also checked this: [Check if Azure Active Directory B2C verification code was sent via email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963458/check-if-azure-active-directory-b2c-verification-code-was-sent-via-email?rq=2) to see if i can debug the problem since this is happening for users in various domains and i can reproduce it myself as well so it is not related to a problematic email server on the user's side or the emails ending up in spam folder. Seems like there is no way to get more info if the problem is on the Azure side not sending the email at all and what the issue is really.

Does anyone know if there is some problem and how to fix it? No new customers can currently signup to submit requests to our portal.Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Built in email provider or third party like sendgrid? Have you got your diagnostic logs sent to (azure monitor)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor] as the OTP audit logs are visible in there but would only indicate a request was sent not delivered. Best advise would be to open a support ticket with Microsoft from your main subscription (where the tenant billing is linked to)

Comment: *"From today 2024-03-01"* It's not March yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is mentioned as service disruption on Azure Service Health (regio Europe for me). You can reach Azure Service Health by logging in to your [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) and searching for 'Service Health' in the search bar on top.

**Impact Statement:** Starting at 08:45 UTC on 03 January 2024, you have been identified among a subset of customers whose end users using Azure Active Directory B2C may experience failures for email verification when trying to sign-up or sign-in to B2C applications. Password resets by end users may also experience failures. Retries might be successful. The service on which Azure Active Directory B2C relies on experienced an outage due to the faulty node.

**Current Status:** As a part of mitigation strategy the dependent team is working on exploring possible mitigation workstreams. The previous mitigation actions, taking faulty node out of rotation and adding additional resources were unsuccessful. We apologize for any inconvenience this has caused. The next update will be provided in 3 hours or as events warrant.

---

**Update 19:00 CEST:**

Impact Statement: Between 08:45 UTC and 17:30 UTC on 03 January 2024, you were identified among a subset of customers using Azure Active Directory B2C who may have experienced failures for email verification when attempting to sign-up or sign-in to B2C applications. Password resets by end users may have also experienced failures. Retries may have been successful. The service on which Azure Active Directory B2C relies on experienced an outage due to the faulty nodes.

Mitigation: As a part of mitigation strategy the dependent team fixed the unhealthy nodes and redeployed the service. The backlog data is processed and we monitored the telemetry to confirm that the service health has been recovered.

Next Steps: We will further work with the dependent team to establish the full root cause of the issue to prevent any future occurrences. Stay informed about Azure service issues by creating custom service health alerts: https://aka.ms/ash-videos for video tutorials and https://aka.ms/ash-alerts for how-to documentation.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find this? It seems clear that our subscription is being impacted by this outage but I don't see any alerts anywhere in the Health section.

Comment: Might be localized to specific regions. Can you clarify which region your tenant experiencing the issue is provisioned in, please?

Comment: This is all I'm able to see: Country or region: United States. Data location: United States datacenters.

Comment: Our B2C tenants are deployed in Europe. I updated my answer where to find the Service Health